# How to get the distinct count of values in a python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get the distinct count of values in a python pandas dataframe and write the result to a new column. This is what I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'OrderNo': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3],
   'Barcode': [1234,2345,3456,3456,1234,1234,2345,1234,3456]
    } );

df['barcodeCountPerOrderNo'] = df.groupby(['OrderNo', 'Barcode'])['Barcode'].transform('count')

df['distinctBarcodesPerOrderNo'] = '?'

print df
```

This gives:

```
   Barcode  OrderNo  barcodeCountPerOrderNo distinctBarcodesPerOrder
0     1234        1                       1                       ?
1     2345        1                       1                       ?
2     3456        1                       2                       ?
3     3456        1                       2                       ?
4     1234        2                       2                       ?
5     1234        2                       2                       ?
6     2345        2                       1                       ?
7     1234        3                       1                       ?
8     3456        3                       1                       ?
```

But how can I get the distinctBarcodesPerOrder?

```
   Barcode  OrderNo  barcodeCountPerOrderNo distinctBarcodesPerOrder
0     1234        1                       1                       3
1     2345        1                       1                       3
2     3456        1                       2                       3
3     3456        1                       2                       3
4     1234        2                       2                       2
5     1234        2                       2                       2
6     2345        2                       1                       2
7     1234        3                       1                       2
8     3456        3                       1                       2
```

Comment: you can use `drop_duplicates` method. See the following document for the datails: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: I am sorry but it is not clear how do you suppose to receive __distinctBarcodesPerOrder__ column. Could you clarify? Perhaps __df.distinctBarcodesPerOrder.unique()__ can do the trick?

Comment: that won't work since, I would like to have the count of distinct barcodes per order (df.distinctBarcodesPerOrder.unique() gives the count over the entire dataframe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `map` to get unique values and directly merge them into the original dataframe:

```
df['distinctBarcodesPerOrder'] = df['OrderNo'].map(df.groupby('OrderNo')['Barcode'].nunique())
```

which returns:

```
   Barcode  OrderNo  barcodeCountPerOrderNo  distinctBarcodesPerOrder
0     1234        1                       1                         3
1     2345        1                       1                         3
2     3456        1                       2                         3
3     3456        1                       2                         3
4     1234        2                       2                         2
5     1234        2                       2                         2
6     2345        2                       1                         2
7     1234        3                       1                         2
8     3456        3                       1                         2
```

Comment: for the sake of elegance and simplicity... this is the working and accepted answer. thx!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nunique` to calculate the number of unique barcodes per order

```
Barcode_distinct = df.groupby('OrderNo')['Barcode'].nunique()
```

the result is pandas Series

```
> OrderNo
> 1    3
> 2    2
> 3    2
> Name: Barcode, dtype: int64
```

then you merge this with the original DataFrame

```
df.merge(Barcode_distinct.to_frame(), left_on='OrderNo', right_index=True, suffixes=('', '_unique_per_OrderNo'))
```

the results is

```
>    Barcode  OrderNo  Barcode_unique_per_OrderNo
> 0     1234        1                           3
> 1     2345        1                           3
> 2     3456        1                           3
> 3     3456        1                           3
> 4     1234        2                           2
> 5     1234        2                           2
> 6     2345        2                           2
> 7     1234        3                           2
> 8     3456        3                           2
```

Comment: thanks for being the first with a working solution. I accepted Fabio Lamanna's solution because it was slightly shorter.

Answer (score 1):

```
#If you want a one-liner, you can use apply to get the distinctBarcodesPerOrder for each row. Although this method might be a slow on large dataset. 

df['distinctBarcodesPerOrder'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[df.OrderNo==x.OrderNo,'Barcode'].nunique(), axis=1)

df
Out[237]: 
   Barcode  OrderNo  barcodeCountPerOrderNo  distinctBarcodesPerOrder
0     1234        1                       1                         3
1     2345        1                       1                         3
2     3456        1                       2                         3
3     3456        1                       2                         3
4     1234        2                       2                         2
5     1234        2                       2                         2
6     2345        2                       1                         2
7     1234        3                       1                         2
8     3456        3                       1                         2
```